# Algorithm Analysis Dependant quadratic

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I want to ask for this question, what is the algorithm analysis for this?
outer loop will execute for n + 2 times
how we determine the inner loop? is it (n+1)/2

```
for(int i = 0;i <= n;i++)
    for(int j = n;j>i;j--)
```

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop has `n + 1` iterations.

The inner loop has `n - i` iterations.

To find the overall time complexity, you have to sum the iterations of the inner loop for all the values of `i`:

```
n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1 = (n+1)*n/2 = O(n^2)
```

Comment: hi eran how did you get outer loop n+1 ? assume n = 5 , i counter would 0,1,2,3,4,5 isn't it execute 6 times + 1 more times(check the condition), so the answer isn't it n + 2? im still newbie

Comment: I counted the number of iterations. Asymptotically it doesn't matter if it's n, or n+1, or n+2, or 2*n - all are `O(n)`.

Comment: ohh i see thanks for answering me.last question,in my notes it says dependant loop would be n+1/2 , how did you get n/2 for inner loop?

Comment: I added the iterations of the inner loop for each value of i. When i=0, the inner loop has n iterations, when i=1 the inner loop has n-1 iterations, and so on. That an arithmetic progression whose sum is (first element + last element)*number of elements/2 (see here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Comment: Note that you can't calculate the total complexity by multiplying the # of iterations of the inner loop by the # of iterations of the outer loop, since the number of iterations of the inner loop changes as a function of i. So it's not correct to say I got n/2 for the inner loop. You can say the average number of iterations of the inner loop is n/2.

Comment: The inner loop is executed a variable number of times, from n down to 0, hence *on average* n/2 times.

Answer (score 0):

@Eran's answer works, but it's easier to figure this out without calculating exactly how many iterations there are of the inner loop.

For n/2 iterations of the outer loop (the ones for small `i`), the inner loop iterates at least n/2 times.  So in total you have at least (n/2)<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup>/4 = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

We can also see that the outer loop iterates at most n times, and the inner loop at most n times for all of those, so in total you have at most n<sup>2</sup> inner iterations, which is also O(<sup>2</sup>)